# Discard a card not working?

Tags: star-realms

Ok so I was playing against the AI (Star Realms Android app) today and every time I played a card that should have had my opponent discarding ( Imperial Fighter), it instead made ME discard as I played the card. In addition, the AI still drew 5 cards at the start of their turn. This has to be a bug, right?

Comment: I can't answer directly without seeing what happened, but here are some things you might have backwards that might clear this up. 1) Players draw 5 at the *end* of their turn, not the beginning. 2) Discarding never affects how many cards you *draw*; you always draw the full amount and then *choose* which to discard. 3) In the app, discards happen at the start of the opponent's turn rather than immediately (presumably they changed this rule to speed up async games), so if it's working correctly then *no* player should discard immediately when you play the Fighter.

Comment: If you believe there is a bug you should probably contact the developers as i'm not sure this is a question that can be answered here. The above comment is correct about players drawing 5 cards at end of there turn.  However when you play a card that caused opponent to have to discard you should see a grey arrow pointing down appear by there cards showing the number that they will discard.  That might help explain whats going on.

Comment: If you were playing the campaign, make sure you read the `rules´ page as some of them break the normal rules of Star Realms and it isn´t always immediately obvious what is going on.

Comment: You draw cards at the end of your turn, not at the start. This allows you to discard cards when your opponent cards say so. If you were drawing them at start of your turn most of the time you would have nothing to discard.

Answer (score 2):

The campaign game changes some of the rules, depending on which mission you are playing.

For example, on Mission 3 "A test of strength (hard)", the rules are

> [...] If you would make your opponent discard a card, you gain 2
>   Authority instead. [...]

I'm pretty sure you were playing a mission with special rules.